# Is the partition module exported by primary module interface unit?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-modules

Consider this example

```cpp
// translation C
export module M:C;
```

```cpp
// translation U
export module M:B;
import :C;
```

```cpp
// translation unit T
export module M;
export import :B;  // #1 imports `M:B` and `M:C`
```

[module.unit] says

> All module partitions of a module that are module interface units **shall be directly or indirectly exported by the primary module interface unit** ([module.import]). No diagnostic is required for a violation of these rules.

[module.import] p7 says

> When a module-import-declaration imports a translation unit T, it also imports all translation units **imported** by exported module-import-declarations in T; **such translation units are said to be exported by T**. Additionally, **when a module-import-declaration in a module unit of some module M imports another module unit U of M, it also imports all translation units imported by non-exported module-import-declarations in the module unit purview of U**. These rules can in turn lead to the importation of yet more translation units.

The first part says `T` exports the translation units if an exported **module-import-declaration** in `T` **imports** them.

Since there is a *non-exported module-import-declaration* `import :C;` in `U`, and the **module-import-declaration** at `#1` in the primary module unit of `M` imports another module unit `U` of `M`, therefore the **module-import-declaration** at `#1` also **imports** `C`, according to the part after "Additionally".

Again, since the *module-import-declaration* at `#1` in `T` is exported, it **directly imports** `M:B` and **indirectly imports** `M:C`, therefore `M:B` and `M:C` are exported by `T`.

So, all partition module interface units are exported by the primary module interface unit. However, when compiling the example with GCC: `g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts c.cpp u.cpp t.cpp`, it reports the error:

```
interface partition is not exported
```

Is it a bug of GCC or the partition `C` is indeed not exported by `T` and the rule is not clear here?

#### Update:

```cpp
// file c
export module C;
export int fun(){return 0;}

// file b
export module M:B;
import C;

// file a
export module M;
export import :B;  // #1
int d = fun();  // #2

// file main
import M;
int main(){}
```

`#2` in this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/csT48ffod) is well-formed. The reason is the exported *module-import-declaration* at `#1` not only **imports** `M:B` but also imports `C` such that the function `fun` can be found at `#2`. So, why don't we agree that TU `C` **imported** by the exported *module-import-declaration* at `#1` in TU `a` is exported by `a`, which is exactly said in the below?

> all translation units **imported** by exported module-import-declarations in T; **such translation units** are said to be exported by T.

This is the part the standard is ambiguous here even though GCC implements the right things which cannot be read from the rule.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, since there is a non-exported module-import-declaration import :C; in U, the module-import-declaration at #1 that imports U therefore also imports C.

That is the *opposite* of what the standard you quoted says. The definition of "exported by T" requires the use of an "exported module-import-declaration in T".

You may have gotten confused because of your use of non-indicative names. I will use the actual module names instead of your translation unit names. What we care about here is the relationships between modules `M`, `M:B`, and `M:C`. `M` imports `M:B`, which imports `M:C`. However, when applying the wording of the standard, we can see that `M:B` import of `M:C` does not use an "exported module-import-declaration". Therefore, `M:C` is not "exported by" `M:B`.

When `M` imports and exports `M:B`, the set of translation units *exported* by this does not include `M:C` because it was not "exported by" `M:B`.

But `M:C` is an interface partition of the module `M`. And by the first rule you quoted, it must be "exported by" `M`, either directly or indirectly.

Therefore, your code is ill-formed.

Comment: @NicoBolas No, the second part says `when a module-import-declaration in a module unit of some module M imports another module unit U of M, it also imports all translation units imported by non-exported module-import-declarations in the module unit purview of U.` The `module-import-declaration` at `#1` imports `B`(which is `U`), since `B` is module unit of `M`, the `module-import-declaration` at `#1` also imports the translation units imported by **non-exported module-import-declarations in the module unit purview of U** (which is `import :C;`).

Comment: @NicoBolas Since the `module-import-declaration` at `#1` that directly imports `B` and indirectly imports `C` is exported in `T`, therefore `B` is directly and `C` is indirectly exported by `T`.

Comment: @xmh0511: Yes, it imports them, but it *doesn't export them*. Is `M:C` "exported by" `M:B`? If the answer to that question is "no", then it isn't exported by someone who imports `M:B`, even if they use `export import` to import it. Nothing in that text makes `export` *transitive*; indeed, the other text makes it clear that "exported by" *requires* the *direct* use of the syntax.

Comment: *Is M:C "exported by" M:B?* we do not care about whether `B` exports `C`. Do you agree the `module-import-declaration` at `#1` imports `C`? You agree that(*Yes, it imports them*).  The first part only says: When a module-import-declaration imports a translation unit T, it also imports **all translation units imported** by **exported module-import-declarations in T**; such translation units are said to be exported by T.  The `export import :B;` **indirectly imports** `C`, why do you think `C` is not exported by `T`?

Comment: @xmh0511: Because `M:B` does not export `M:C`; that's right there in the definition of "exported by". Therefore, `M` cannot have exported it. Just because you import something does not mean you export it ***EVEN IF*** you use an `export import` declaration to recursively import it. It must be `export`ed by the translation unit that *directly* imports it. Not the ones who do so indirectly.

Comment: @xmh0511: Also, stop using the name `T`. It's confusing you, because the standard uses `T`, and you think the `T` it's talking about is the same one as yours. It's not.

Comment: `T` exports another translation unit if the translation unit is imported by **exported module-import-declarations** in T. This means all translation units that are imported by such a module-import-declaration in **T** (include the directly and indirectly imported by such a module-import-declaration). `M:C` is **indirectly imported** by the exported module-import-declaration in `T`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245614/discussion-between-xmh0511-and-nicol-bolas).

Comment: @xmh0511: "*This means all translation units that are imported by such a module-import-declaration in `T`*" Again, you are confusing your `T`s. The question is very simple: does `M:B` export `M:C`? If the answer to that question is "no", then anything which imports `M:B` *will not* export `M:C`, because `M:C` is not "exported by" `M:B`. Because there is no `export` declaration which specifies `M:C`.

Comment: You have the patience of a saint, @Nicol.  You needed it with me once...

Comment: @PaulSanders Nicol has been patient to interpret the behavior of GCC and appreciates it. However, he agreed that `M:C` is imported by `export import :B;`, but he didn't agree that `M:C` is exported by PMI of `M`. This is the divergence of interpreting "all translation units imported by exported module-import-declarations in T; such translation units are said to be exported by T" between him and me. I convey that "such translation units" refer to all translation units that are **imported** by `export import :B;`.